# I can't use jQuery library, and I am getting TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null when 'translating' to pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't use jQuery library on my project so I need to get this little jQuery snippet to 'pure' javscript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$listHeight = $('ul#home-news-list').height();
$child = $('ul#home-news-list li:last-child');
while ($listHeight > 150) {
    $($child).remove();
    $listHeight = $('#home-news-inner ul').height();
    $child = $('ul#home-news-list li:last-child');
    console.log($listHeight);
    }
});
```

So it basically removes the last list item until list height is less than 150. My javascript skills are not that good so this is the code I came up with and it gives me `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` on the first line, so I have no idea if the rest is worth anything:

```
var listHeight = document.getElementById('home-news-list').offsetHeight();
var child = document.getElementById('home-news-list li:last-child');
while (listHeight > 150) {
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    var listHeight = document.getElementById('home-news-list').offsetHeight();
    child = document.getElementById('home-news-list li:last-child');
}
```

Could you please tell me what I wrong with the code?

I am calling this script in `<head></head>`

Comment: I feel sorry for you for not being allowed to use jQuery, and wish you get a better job in a place where it is allowed.

Comment: Where have you put your javascript code for the 'pure' version?  The jQuery code is running in the 'document.ready' function, having hooked the window.load.  Is your code running before the DOM has rendered by any chance?

Comment: Not sure, but i suggest to put script tag just before end of body tag and try once

Comment: You can't find dom elements using `document.getElementById('home-news-list li:last-child');` in javascript. jquery makes it easy for one to find, with its selectors.

Comment: First as VJD say put your javascript at the bottom of the html, then if you want to use css query selectors to get html elements you can use document.querySelector("home-news-list li:last-child");

Comment: If you want to use css selectors like jquery does then you can use javascript's `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` methods.

Comment: @Paddy I moved it above </body> it's picking up alright, changed .offsetHeight() to offsetHeght;, and now I get 'TypeError: child is null' on 'child.parentNode.removeChild(child);' which child is null? 

edit: used advices from above - works like a charm, you guys are great!

Comment: You also seem to lack the essential `$(document).ready()` wrapper, and try to invoke the numerical `offsetHeight` property. Also, you should consider using a `do-while`-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use css selectors like jquery does then you can use javascript's querySelector and querySelectorAll methods.

```
var listHeight = document.getElementById('home-news-list').offsetHeight();
var child = document.querySelector('home-news-list li:last-child');
while (listHeight > 150) {
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    var listHeight = document.getElementById('home-news-list').offsetHeight();
    child = document.querySelector('home-news-list li:last-child');
}
```

This is the same as you code but with `querySelector` substituted when `getElementByid` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem seems to be the use of getElementById, this method call can't be used with the same parameters as JQuery and so becomes cubersome and more verbose within pur javascript, also offsetHeight is a property instead of a method:

```
var listHeight = document.getElementById('home-news-list').offsetHeight;
var parent = document.getElementById('home-news-list');
var child = parent.lastChild;
while (listHeight > 150) {
    child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
    listHeight = document.getElementById('home-news-list').offsetHeight;
    child = parent.lastChild;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, your script in `<head>` will execute immediately before the browser has a chance to parse your DOM; so you should place the script at the **bottom** of the page, and to ensure that the script executes only when the DOM is ready:

```
window.onload = function () { 
    ...
};
```

The first line should work if you change offsetHeight() to offsetHeight (it's a property, not method). For the rest, you need to dig through CSS selector and DOM api to figure out how jQuery do it...

I'm sorry that you can't use jQuery, the DOM API is a terrifying monster.